# Footer always at very bottom (move with content, but min at bottom)

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to set up a website with header, body and footer. I want the footer to be at the very bottom of the page but move it relative to the content. Here is what I got so far

html:

```
<html>
   <header>
   </header>
   <body>
      <div id="header">
      </div>
      <div id="body">
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
* { 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
}
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
html, body { 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
}
#header {
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
}
#body {
    min-height:74.3%;
    width:100%;

    padding-top   : 10%; 
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#footer {      
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

On my resolution (Retina) everything is working fine, but when testing on lower resolutions the footer appears above the page bottom if the content of `<div id="body"></div>` is not enough to fill the whole page.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; /* This line and the next line are not necessary unless you need IE6 support */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 155px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

Another Example : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: Thanks, this does fix the footer to the bottom of the page. There is only one problem. When adding content to the page using javascript, the footer won't move. Removing the wrapper height seems to fix the problem, but the footer will not move down the height of the new content. :(

Comment: Fixed it by myself :) Just remove the wrappers hight and set up the push height double the footer, everything is fine now, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a **sticky footer**,

the quickest approach is to wrap all your content except footer and set a margin-bottom of the size of the footer height, so in your case you should also wrap the header, here's a general ex.:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -66px; 
}
//for clearfix
wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 66px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: tomato;
}
```

there's also other methods of doing this ,  [check this out](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/apuvpktt/) for you:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">

  <h1>Sticky Footer</h1>
  <h2>with Fixed Footer Height</h2> 

</div>

<div id="bottomArea">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#main {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin:0 auto -142px auto; 
    background:#FCF;
}
#main:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
#bottomArea, #main:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
    height: 142px; 
}
#bottomArea {
  background: orange;
}
```